# Making axios call in render does not return anything

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios, jsx

I am making an axios call in the render of my react native app.

```
render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
        <ScrollView
          style={styles.scrollView}
          contentContainerStyle={{justifyContent: 'center'}}>
          <Text style={styles.heading}>Checked Out Books</Text>
          {this.state.books.map((book) => {
            axios
              .get('http://localhost:3000/books/id/' + book)
              .then((res) => {
                console.log(res.data);
                return (
                  <View>
                    <Image
                      source={{uri: res.data.cover}}
                      height={150}
                      width={110}></Image>
                    <Text>{res.data.title}</Text>
                  </View>
                );
              })
              .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
                alert('Something went wrong.');
              });
          })}
```

When the call finishes and it gets to the return step, nothing is returned.

I don't know why this is happening.
This segment of code is not returned:

```
<View>
  <Image
      source={{uri: res.data.cover}}
      height={150}
      width={110}></Image>
      <Text>{res.data.title}</Text>
</View>
```

Why is this?

Comment: You're not returning anything in `map`

Comment: Oh, how would I do that? Sorry I'm new to react native

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the comment that you are not returning anything from `.map()`, an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#syntax) either needs to have no brackets like `(book) => axios.get(` or have brackets and use the word `return` like `(book) => { return axios.get(`.

The `return` statement that you are looking at with the `<View>` element is the `return` for the `.then()` callback function, not for the whole `.map()` function.

But this is **not** going to solve your issue because the value that you would be returning from the `.map()` is a `Promise`, which is not something that you can print out in your component JSX.

@jamielarchin is correct that you cannot do data fetching inside your `render()` method.  It needs to be inside of a lifecycle method like `componentDidMount` or `componentDidUpdate` or inside of a `useEffect` hook.  Since you are just learning, I recommend that you learn with the most current approach which is to use a function component and `useEffect`.

I recommend that you handle the data fetching for each book in a separate `Book` component rather than dealing with fetching data in a loop.  This is much simpler and it avoids having to refetch the entire list if just one book changes.

You can make that `Book` component be a function component and keep your current "list of books" component as a class component.

```
// the book id is the only prop
const Book = ({ id }) => {
  const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  // save the book data here, once loaded
  const [data, setData] = useState();

  useEffect(
    () => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      axios
        .get('http://localhost:3000/books/id/' + id)
        .then((res) => setData(res.data))
        .catch((err) => setIsError(true))
        .finally(() => setIsLoading(false));
    },
    [id] // dependency on the book id
  );

  if (data !== undefined) {
    return (
      <View>
        <Image source={{ uri: data.cover }} height={150} width={110}></Image>
        <Text>{data.title}</Text>
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }
  // can show loading and error components too
  // but for now I'm just returning nothing
  return null;
};
```

```
render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
        <ScrollView
          style={styles.scrollView}
          contentContainerStyle={{justifyContent: 'center'}}>
          <Text style={styles.heading}>Checked Out Books</Text>
          {this.state.books.map((book) => <Book id={book} key={book}/>)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Data fetching should be done from a lifecycle method for class components. You probably want to use componentDidMount: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't make an axios call inside render (it is possible with some adjustments however it is not a good practice). You should either use hooks (like useEffect) if you are in a functional component or use componentDidMount if you are in a class component (which I assume you are). Examples are shown below.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    this.state = {
        bookIds: [], //You would fill this beforehand
        books: [],
      }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    for(let i = 0; i < bookIds; i++){
      axios.get('http://localhost:3000/books/id/' + bookIds[i]).then((res) => {
         books.push(res); 
       }.catch((err) => {
           console.log(err);
           alert('Something went wrong.');
      });
    }
  }


  render() {
    return(
        <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
        <ScrollView
          style={styles.scrollView}
          contentContainerStyle={{justifyContent: 'center'}}>
          <Text style={styles.heading}>Checked Out Books</Text>
          {this.state.books.map((book) => {
             return (
               <View>
                 <Image
                   source={{uri: book.data.cover}}
                   height={150}
                   width={110}>
                 </Image>
                 <Text>{book.data.title}</Text>
               </View>
            );
        })
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Would recommend you take a look at this: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html.

There might be some issues with the brackets, Have a great day!